# How to resolve the error unable to open input file in Verilog?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, multiplexer

I was asked to implement a 16-to-1 multiplexer using a 4-to-1 multiplexer using the conditional statement. Writing the Verilog code and the testbench code wasn't a big issue however I'm unable to understand what I can do to resolve the **error unable to open input file**.  See the Verilog and testbench code below.

The simulator used for obtaining the waveforms is GTKWave. The Verilog code and testbench code are saved in `C:\iverilog\bin\MultiplexersLab`

Here is the Verilog code (file name: `mux16to1.v`):

```
module mux16to1(w,s,f);
input [15:0] w;
input [3:0] s;
output f;
wire [3:0]x;
mux4to1 m1(w[3:0],s[1:0],x[0]);
mux4to1 m2(w[7:4],s[1:0],x[1]);
mux4to1 m3(w[11:8],s[1:0],x[2]);
mux4to1 m4(w[15:12],s[1:0],x[3]);
mux4to1 m5(x,s[1:0],f);
endmodule 

module mux4to1(w,s,f);
input [3:0]w;
input [1:0]s;
output f;
reg f;
always @(w or s)
f = s[1]?(s[0]?w[3]:w[2]):(s[0]?w[1]:w[0]);
endmodule
```

Testbench code (file name: `exercise2_tb.v`):

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
`include "mux16to1.v"
module exercise2_tb();
reg[15:0] w;
reg[3:0] s;
wire f;

mux16to1 test(w,s,f);
initial 
begin
    $dumpfile("exercise2.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0,exercise2_tb);
    w = 16'b0000000000000001; s = 4'b0000;#20;
    w = 16'b1000000000000000; s = 4'b1111;#20;
    w = 16'b0000000000000010; s = 4'b0010;#20;
    w = 16'b0000010000000000; s = 4'b0101;#20;

    $display("Test Complete");

end
endmodule
```

Output Generated:

```
PS C:\iverilog\bin\MultiplexersLab> iverilog -o exericse2_tb.vvp exercise2_tb.v
PS C:\iverilog\bin\MultiplexersLab> vvp exercise2_tb.vvp
exercise2_tb.vvp: Unable to open input file.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `vvp` command tells you that the file named `exercise2_tb.vvp` does not exist.  It does not exist because you specified an output file named `exericse2_tb.vvp` on the `iverilog` command line (different spelling: exer**ci**se2 vs. exer**ic**se2).

To run `vvp` on the file you created, change:

```
vvp exercise2_tb.vvp
```

to:

```
vvp exericse2_tb.vvp
```

With that change, I see the following output:

```
VCD info: dumpfile exercise2.vcd opened for output.
Test Complete
```

---

Or, change the `iverilog` command to:

```
iverilog -o exercise2_tb.vvp exercise2_tb.v
```